# Convert address to Geo coordinates in android

Tags: android, geolocation, coordinates

Is it possible to convert specific address to longitude/latitude (coordinates) in android? if so please anyone let me know how to do so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use the below to get the address

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
```

To reverse the getting a lat long from a location do the below

```
    Geocoder geocoder =  new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    geocoder.getFromLocationName(<Insert Example Address>)
```

Supporting documentation from Google...

```
/**
     * Returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the
     * named location, which may be a place name such as "Dalvik,
     * Iceland", an address such as "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway,
     * Mountain View, CA", an airport code such as "SFO", etc..  The
     * returned addresses will be localized for the locale provided to
     * this class's constructor.
     *
     * <p> The query will block and returned values will be obtained by means of a network lookup.
     * The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or
     * correct. It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your
     * primary UI thread.
     *
     * @param locationName a user-supplied description of a location
     * @param maxResults max number of results to return. Smaller numbers (1 to 5) are recommended
     *
     * @return a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were
     * found or there is no backend service available.
     *
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if locationName is null
     * @throws IOException if the network is unavailable or any other
     * I/O problem occurs
     */
```

Comment: Geocoder geocoder =  new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    geocoder.getFromLocationName(<Insert Example Address>) using this how we can split the longitude and latitude separately? I wanna use implicit map intent, it doesn't support to list of address, how to solve this?